# How to generate a RSAPublicKey to feed into JJWT RSA token validation

Tags: azure, rsa, jjwt

I'm validating a JWT token coming from Azure and use JJWT. I retrieve the modulus and exponent from the keys document related to my tid, which are fields
n and e respectively. The validation fails with error: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.

This is the code. Does anybody see the mistake i made? The code runs fine all up to the validation where it throws the signature mismatch error.

```
private Claims extractClaimsForRsaSignedJwts(String token, String mod, String exp) {
    Claims claims = null;
    byte[] modBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(mod.getBytes());
    byte[] expBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(exp.getBytes());
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(modBytes);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(expBytes);
    RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpecification = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
    KeyFactory keyFac = null;
    try {
        keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    RSAPublicKey rsaPub = null;
    try {
        rsaPub = (RSAPublicKey) keyFac.generatePublic(pubKeySpecification);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(rsaPub);

    try {
        claims = jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
        System.out.println("The RSA JWT key validation failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return claims;
}
```

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem! the BigInteger should be constructed with signum 1 for positve numbers! Now the code works like a charm for AzureAD JWT signature validation.

```
    BigInteger modulus  = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);
```

This is the final code:
[Screen Shot Of Code With Correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZTs.jpg)